# Android add custom phonenumber

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentresolver

i want to add a custom phonenumber to a given contact.

My Code is:

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for (PhoneContact phoneContact : this.phoneContactList) {
        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.parseInt(phoneContact.getId()))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, "ABCDE")
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, PhoneNumberFormatter.formatNumber(ctx, "1232444444"))
                    .build());
            contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    return null;
}
```

But when i run this code, nothing will hapend.
Can everyone help me?

Comment: Did you included the required permissions in your manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
```